# Restrict angular route by domain or ip address?

Tags: angular

Is it possible to restrict an angular route by ip address or domain?

I am currently using angular 4 with asp.net web api 2.  I have an admin route, but I only want the admin route to be accessed by particular ips or a domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to access IP address of a client only with JS. See this question's answer: 
[How to get client's IP address using javascript only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/how-to-get-clients-ip-address-using-javascript-only)

There are simple solutions in a form of API that will return you your public ip.

As for domain name you can use `window` object from JS to see what domain name is present:

`window.location.host' will return you domain name.

As for forbidding access to some routes you can use Angular guarding concept for that purpose:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#can-activate-guard

Comment: So in combination with canActivate, I can probably make a request to a server side api that will return some authorization if the request came from a certain IP?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Actually you can make a simple request to your server that can ready IP address and actually return to your guard success or fail based on read IP address of client.